# how to print the file using awk

Tags: awk

INPUT (tab delimited)

```
HTR12   AT1G01370       Chr1    143564  145684  +
SDG42   AT1G01920       Chr1    316128  319650  +
SDG5    AT1G02580       Chr1    544783  549202  +
```

OUTPUT (tab delimited)

```
Chr1    143564  145684  HTR12   AT1G01370       +
Chr1    316128  319650  SDG42   AT1G01920       +
Chr1    544783  549202  SDG5    AT1G02580       +
```

my solution is

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $3,$4,$5,$2,$1,$6}' input > output
```

But seems not good.

Comment: Any chance of seeing what *seems not good* really is? BTW, I think you mean `awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $3,$4,$5,$1,$2,$6}' input > output`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $3,$4,$5,$1,$2,$6}' input > output
```

this will set FS (field separator) for both

- `-F'\t'` IFS (input),
- `-v OFS='\t'` OFS (output).

I also swap `$1` and `$2`

I tabbed you sample files, output is

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $3,$4,$5,$1,$2,$6}' se.txt
Chr1    143564  145684  HTR12   AT1G01370       +
Chr1    316128  319650  SDG42   AT1G01920       +
```

and (add `od -c` to check for tab)

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{print $3,$4,$5,$1,$2,$6}' se.txt | od -c
0000000   C   h   r   1  \t   1   4   3   5   6   4  \t   1   4   5   6
0000020   8   4  \t   H   T   R   1   2  \t   A   T   1   G   0   1   3
0000040   7   0  \t   +  \n   C   h   r   1  \t   3   1   6   1   2   8
0000060  \t   3   1   9   6   5   0  \t   S   D   G   4   2  \t   A   T
0000100   1   G   0   1   9   2   0  \t   +      \n
0000113
```

Answer (score 0):

i Use space as field separator and tab in between fields i got perfect orientation.

```
awk -F" " '{print $3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$2"\t"$1"\t"$6}' input.txt > output.txt
```

output:

```
Chr1     143564  145684  AT1G01370   HTR12   +
Chr1     316128  319650  AT1G01920   SDG42   +
Chr1     544783  549202  AT1G02580   SDG5    +
```

Comment: It's unclear why you would choose to use space as the input field separator and why you output explicit tabs instead of setting `OFS="\t"`. Also, note the ordering of the fields in the output compared to what's in the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: remove `,` from print as it insert space after tab.

Comment: Said differently, the question explicitly says: "INPUT (tab delimited)". Perhaps you copy/pasted the input locally and it resulted in spaces instead of tabs? See also Archemar's answer for the output field ordering -- it's ... 1/2/6, not  2/1/6 (which was maybe the OP's problem all along??). But at which point, you've basically recreated Archemar's answer.

Answer (score -1):

One tab is equal to 8 spaces  so try with below code

```
awk '{printf "%8s%8s%8s%8s%8s%8s\n",$3,$4,$5,$1,$2,$6}' filename

    Chr1  143564  145684   HTR12AT1G01370       +
    Chr1  316128  319650   SDG42AT1G01920       +
    Chr1  544783  549202    SDG5AT1G02580       +
```